# How to create TypedTable from names (strings) and vectors?

Tags: julia

Consider

```
import TypedTables as TT
TT.Table(this=[1,2,3])
```

Fine. Now instead I have

```
a = "this"
b = [1,2,3]
```

How do I create the same table from `a` and `b`? Going via a NamedTyple is a bit round about but seems to work:

```
TT.Table((; Symbol(a) =>b))
```

Is a less round about approach available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip `NamedTuple` construction and just pass this as `kwargs`:

```
julia> Table(;Symbol(a) =>b)
Table with 1 column and 3 rows:
     this
   ┌─────
 1 │ 1
 2 │ 2
 3 │ 3
```

Regarding the multi-column comments:

```
julia> as = ["this", "that"];

julia> bs = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];

julia> Table(; (Symbol.(as) .=> bs)...)
Table with 2 columns and 3 rows:
     this  that
   ┌───────────
 1 │ 1     4
 2 │ 2     5
 3 │ 3     6
```

Comment: So then, `Table(; zip(map(Symbol,as),bs)...)` for bigger tables. I see that it works. Is it the way?

Comment: `Table(; (Symbol.(as) .=> bs)...)` should also work instead of that. And, perhaps, `Table(NamedTuple{as}(bs))`, if `as` is already a `Symbol` tuple (I didn't test the latter, but the [source](https://github.com/JuliaData/TypedTables.jl/blob/main/src/Table.jl#L18) looks like it should work).

Comment: Ah yes; nice. I hope you add `TT.Table(; (Symbol.(as) .=> bs)...)` to your answer.